# Does firefox have a "fit" button equivalent in inspector like chrome?

Tags: responsive-design, firefox-developer-tools

If you go to the chrome's inspector, there is a "fit" button right at the top which is very handy in responsive design. It tries to fit the viewport in chrome with any screen resolution you set.
Does firefox have a feature like this? And how can I use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, we currently don't have this feature in Firefox's Responsive Design mode.  It seems nice to have on a small screen or for a large device!  I've filed a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1213951) to add it.

We'll be refreshing Responsive Design later this year, so I hope we'll be able to include this feature then.

Comment: any update on this bug ?

Comment: @AnshumanSingh As you can see, the bug is currently still open and the feature has not yet been implemented. The bug is the place to look for updates.

Answer (score -5):

Yes, Firefox does have a responsive design mode: 
[image: Responsive Design Mode]

Just click the responsive design mode button in Firefox F12 tools. If you don't see it, click the gear for options, then check the "Responsive Design Mode" checkbox.

Comment: Hello, read the question again, it's not about whether Firefox has a design mode or not.